# Css scrolling doesn't work when trying to scroll, scroll bar is there but no scrolling is achieved

Tags: html, css

I have searched everywhere without any result, tried multiple solutions but with no result. The problem is that I can't scroll even though there is a scrollbar.

Code:
Html:

```css
#schedule em, #info_holder em{
  font-style: normal;
}
#schedule .day_div li, #info_holder li {
  position: relative;
  /* background-color: red; */
  color: white;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);

  border-radius: 5px;
}

#schedule .day_div li::after, #info_holder li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  /* z-index: -1; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out; */
}
#schedule .day_div:nth-child(2) li, #info_holder li.two{
  background: rgb(60,225,226);
  background: linear-gradient(315deg, rgba(60,225,226,1) 0%, rgba(28,55,172,1) 100%);
}
#schedule .day_div li a, #info_holder li a {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  /* width: 100%;
  height: 100%; */
  padding: calc(0.75* 1.25em);
}
#schedule .day_div li div, #info_holder li div {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: calc(0.75*1rem);
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 60%;
  /* asdfghjklöä */
}
#schedule .day_div li a em, #info_holder li a em{
  font-size: calc(var(--main-text-size)*0.8);
}
#schedule .day_div li.content_cutoff a::before, #info_holder li.content_cutoff a::before {
  display: inline-block;
}
#schedule .day_div li a::before, #info_holder li a::before {
  content: attr(data-start) " - " attr(data-end);
  display: block;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: calc(var(--main-text-size)*0.9);
}
#schedule .day_div li a.databefore::before, #info_holder li a.databefore::before {
  content: attr(data-before);
}
#schedule .day_div li a em, #info_holder li a em {
  font-size: calc(var(--main-text-size)*1.2);
}
#info_holder {
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: var(--main-text-size);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
}
#info_holder li{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
}
#info_holder li a:not(:nth-child(1)) {
  opacity: 0;

  transition: opacity .3s;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="info_holder" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);">
   <li class="two" style="top: 20%; height: 60%; left: 20%; width: 60%;" data-start_top="76.796875" data-start_left="173" data-start_width="238" data-end_width="100">
      <a data-start="08:00" data-end="09:00"><em>Matte</em></a><a data-before="Lärare" class="databefore" style="opacity: 1; left: calc(110px + 0.9375em);"><em>Göran</em></a><a data-before="Klassrum" class="databefore" style="opacity: 1; left: calc(189px + 0.9375em);"><em>Katedralen</em></a><a data-before="Inställd?" class="databefore" style="opacity: 1; left: calc(307px + 0.9375em);"><em>Ja</em></a>
      <div style="opacity: 1; top: calc(72px + 0.46875em);"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span></div>
   </li>
</div>
```

You can scroll when hovering over just the text (not in the blue ish box.). So go into full page to see result more clearly.

Here is the code in jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Snakehater/uhL04p81/2/

please ask for more information.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: IT seems the problem is in the .two class. if you add a border to it you can see it is positioned over the text

Comment: I tried to disable the .two class with no difference more than that the gradient background got removed.

Comment: Your after pseudoelement with no content (`#info_holder li::after`) is over the whole div and disable every interaction with element under it. Remove him.

Comment: @PetrUnzeitig you should post it as an answer, this is the correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your after pseudoelement with no content (`#info_holder li::after`) is over the whole div and disable every interaction with element under it. Remove him.